# Pod unable to curl localhost

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

There is an elastic search container running on localhost on port 9200, but from a pod on the same host, I'm unable to curl the localhost port 9200

```
[root@jenkins ~]# netstat -tupln | grep 9200
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      4148/docker-proxy


[jenkins@kb-s-9xttg agent]$ curl http://localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ::1: Network is unreachable
```

/etc/hosts

```
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.255.23  kbs-9xttg
```

I am able to `curl public_host_ip:9200`

elastic-search container is not managed by Kubernetes but running on the same host.

Why is the pod unable to talk to `localhost:9200` or `127.0.0.1:9200` ?

Comment: You're talking to "localhost" inside the same pod, not to the other pod. Curling the IP of the pod should work, as well as adding a service. Unless you're using the host network you have three different localhosts. One on the node, and one per pod.

Comment: @char Thanks for your time, es container is not part of any pod, its a container, another build agent container inside a pod is trying to access localhost:9200, where curl is failing as above, not sure why. On the host vm curl works fine, so no firewall issues.

Comment: So you're running a container separate from your Kubernetes? Localhost inside a pod usually points to inside the pod. When you're running a container on your node outside of Kubernetes it's using the host network, and is then exposing the port via your host's localhost.

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746508/how-to-access-local-machine-from-a-pod) explains it a bit better

Comment: @char yes your right es container is running outside k8s. So there is no way for the pod to talk to host's localhost ?

Comment: You could curl the public IP of your host. Or try running your pod in host network mode (`spec:
  hostNetwork: true`), though I'm not 100% certain if that works.

Comment: Thanks @char will try it out!

Comment: Host network mode will cause port conflicts so its not an ideal way to proceed here, hope to find a better solution to the problem. Thanks @char

Comment: @char, could you post an answer based on your comments ? @Sanjay I guess the above comments clarified your doubts when it comes to `Pod` networking in kubernetes ?

Comment: @mario yes pretty much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Summary from the comments:*

If you're talking to localhost from within a Pod, you're only talking to the containers inside that Pod.

Containers in different Pods have distinct IP addresses and can not communicate by using localhost. They might however be exposing their own port on your local host network, similar to what your Docker container is doing (which is why you can communicate from your local node using localhost).

Inside your cluster you can use the Pod IPs, but if you want to talk to your host you need to use host networking for your Pod

```
spec:
   hostNetwork: true
```

or the external IP of your host.

More on [Kubernetes Networking in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) and [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-pods-7117dd28727).